# ASP.Net Core Performance on Azure vs Local

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a website with a function that generates a report in Excel that is pretty much just a datadump, approx 16000 rows, using EPPlus. This report keeps timing out for the users on Azure. The timeout (524) is a cloudflare limit if the request takes longer than 100 seconds.

I have optimised the hell out of it using Hashsets and Dictionaries, and it now runs in under 2 seconds on my laptop in Debug. I've also tried publishing with the target runtime as win-x64, in case it's a memory allocation issue.

Initially I thought the bottleneck would be memory. After setting up Application Insights, I can see that the CPU is at 100% while the memory is fairly low, about 300MB. I've bumped the Service Plan up to the P3V2 (14GB RAM & 840 ACU) to test if it's just a resource allocation issue. Even at that level, it takes about 50-60 seconds to produce. I can't run the app at that level, so I need to get it down much lower.

I'm not sure how else to optimise this, or identify the bottleneck. Any ideas?

Comment: It's impossible to help without any code. 16K rows isn't a lot. Unless the query itself is slow. Hashsets and dictionaries wouldn't help with a simple query and a `LoadFromCollection` or `LoadFromDataReader`

Comment: You could try using the [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0) class in conjunction with the [TrackEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#api-summary) method on the Application Insights object to gain some insight into what parts are slow. You could also try the built-in [Dependency Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#diagnosis) functionality.